# FIFO getch/ungetch Functions

Tags: beginner, c, io

I'm currently working myself through *K&R* and just read about implementing `getch()` and `ungetch()`.

In *K&R* these functions are implemented like this:

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> #define BUFSIZE 100
> char buf[BUFSIZE];     /* buffer for ungetch */
> int bufp = 0;          /* next free position in buf */
>
> int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */
> {
>     return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
> }
>
> void ungetch(int c)    /* push character back on input */
> {
>     if (bufp >= BUFSIZE)
>         printf("ungetch: too many characters\n");
>     else
>         buf[bufp++] = c;
> }
> ```

As you can see this is implemented like a stack (last in -> first out). This somehow bothers me. In the example:

```
ungetch('a');
ungetch('b');
ungetch('c');
```

`getch()`will return 'c' at the first function call. 'b' on the second function call and 'a' on the third function call. I liked the idea of getting the first `'ungetch()'`-ed char at the start and the last `'ungetch'`-ed char in the end.

This is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define BUFSIZE 10
static int reorder_buf(void);

char buf[BUFSIZE];
int bufrp = 0;    //buffer read position
int bufwp = 0;    //buffer write position

int getch(void)
{
    if (bufrp < bufwp)
        return buf[bufrp++];
    else {
        if(bufwp != 0)
            bufwp = bufrp = 0;

        return getchar();
    }
}

void ungetch(int c)
{
    if (bufwp < BUFSIZE)
        buf[bufwp++]=c;
    else
    {
        if (reorder_buf() != 0)     //successful reorder
        {
            buf[bufwp++]=c;
        } else                      //full buffer
        {
            printf("Failed to ungetch(%c).\n", c);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Tries to move buffer content to the start of the buffer.
 *
 * @return 1 on successful reorder, 0 otherwise
 */
static int reorder_buf(void)
{
    if (bufrp > 0)
    {
        int i;
        for(i = 0; bufrp < bufwp; bufrp++, i++)
             buf[i] = buf[bufrp];

        bufrp = 0;
        bufwp = i;
        return 1;
     } else
     {
         return 0;
     }
}
```

I also had the idea to replace the error message in `ungetch()` with returning an int, which includes the information if the unget process was successful and provides it to the caller.

Comment: Well, `ungetch` undoes a single `getch`. It doesn't make sense to undo an operation before you undid whatever else you did afterwards....

Comment: But what if I read a whole word in and want to push it back into input?

Comment: Then you push it back byte-for-byte, in the reverse order you read it.

Comment: Note that the [tag:curses] library has an [`ungetch()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcurses/ungetch.html) function. It sidesteps the FIFO-vs.-LIFO issue by guaranteeing a buffer of just one character; the behaviour of a second successive `ungetch()` call is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reorder_buf()` is horribly inefficient, and it's unnecessary if you use the buffer as a [circular-list](/questions/tagged/circular-list).  What you want is called a ring buffer.

```
/* Store up to 10 characters */
#define BUFSIZE 11

char buf[BUFSIZE];
int qhead = 0, qtail = 0;

int getch(void) {
    if (qhead != qtail) {
        int c = buf[qhead];
        qhead = (qhead + 1) % BUFSIZE;
        return c;
    } else {
        return getchar();
    }
}

void ungetch(int c) {
    if ((qtail + 1) % BUFSIZE == qhead) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Buffer full, dropped %c.\n", c);
    } else {
        buf[qtail] = c;
        qtail = (qtail + 1) % BUFSIZE;
    }
}
```

Errors should go to `stderr` rather than `stdout`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ungetch` has *very* strange behavior on error.
I'm not quite sure whether it's better or worse than [`On Error Resume Next`](//stackoverflow.com/questions/2202869/what-does-the-on-error-resume-next-statement-do), but it's certainly in the same class.

Either handle it yourself, which means reporting an error *to `stderr`* and aborting the program, or report it to the caller (see the docs on [`ungetc`](//en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ungetc) for a way).
At the moment, you print an error-message (which might get lost in the output, and anyway there's a human actively and attentively monitoring things), but then happily move on with data-loss and without informing the caller.